# Mule Https request response timeout

Tags: https, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Im trying to config a response timeout for https request component.
My http connector is calling a URL, I want to set a time for example after 5 second if there is no response back from the URL close this https connection.
But I've been searched on google and mule site there are no related information.
This webservice i am calling resets password, if after certain time I don't get response I want to close it and DO NOT want to reset it.

Here is the sample code:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="10.255.255.1." port="2446" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"  responseTimeout="1" usePersistentConnections="false">
```

The responseTimeout is not doing anything, I've tried using SOAPUI to test the time is still the same no matter what I put.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have set the responseTimeout property in the Http- request config and it works for me.

Please find the code below

```
<!--Http Listener Config for calling Service-->
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" host="0.0.0.0" port="8092" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8092" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" responseTimeout="5000"/>

    <flow name="testtimeoutFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/test" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <logger message="#[message.exception]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <set-payload value="#['Time out Error']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>

<!-- Flow which has delay in responding the data-->
    <flow name="testtimeoutFlow1">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="GET"/>
        <set-payload value="#['HelloWorld']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<!-- Delay for 10 seconds-->
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[sleep(10000);
return message.payload;]]>
  </scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <logger message="After Script : #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Hope this helps.